# reset TinyMCE`s cancel button

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I'm using TinyMCE with jQuery for posting comment. When I post my comment, I want to reset the TinyMCE , reset the TinyMCE cancel button and so on.

[image]

```
tinyMCE.init({
    menubar: false,
    plugins: [
        'fullscreen code paste table contextmenu advlist autolink lists link'
    ]
    ,language: 'zh_CN'
    ,toolbar: 'undo redo | insert | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent  | fullscreen code'
    ,selector:'#comment'
    ,paste_merge_formats: true
    ,paste_word_valid_elements: "b,strong,i,em,h1,h2"
    ,setup: function(editor) {
        editor.on('keydown change', function() {
            comment = editor.getContent();
        });
    }
});  

 tinyMCE.editors[0].setContent("");   //can make tinyMCE comment empty
```

But I want tinyMCE cancel button gray

Comment: then just make it gray. or actually tell us what you tried and why it didn't work.

Comment: tinyMCE.editors[0].init();     last night finally,i use it.  make tinyMCE init. it work!   thx

Comment: @nonchip  
// tinyMCE.editors[0].setContent("");   
 // tinyMCE.editors[0].init()
 tinymce.get('comment').init();  
in IE9,thiere are not work.

Comment: i meant tell us in your question, not by dumping them into a single line of comment -_-

Answer (score 1):

Are you wanting to reset the `undo` button (not sure what you mean by the `cancel` button)?  If so you just do this:

```
tinyMCE.editors[0].undoManager.clear();
```